# Confidence interval calculation: why sometimes the SD is dividted by the sqrt of sample size, and sometimes not?

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, variance

I have trouble understanding the following:

Looking how reference ranges for laboratory values are calculated, I found the following:

> In our sample of 72 printers, the standard error of the mean was 0.53
> mmHg. The sample mean plus or minus 196 times its standard error gives
> the following two figures:
> 88 + (1.96 x 0.53) = 89.04 mmHg
> 88 – (1.96
> x 0.53) = 86.96 mmHg.
> This is called the 95% confidence interval , and we can say that there
> is only a 5% chance that the range 86.96 to 89.04 mmHg excludes the
> mean of the population.

That is clear to me: I multiply the Z for 2 SD by the value of SD and subtract and add it to the mean to define the limits.

However, I often see another definition of CI, that divides the SD by the square root of the number of samples. The result is therefore quite different, in this case, it would be 88 ± 0.122 (vs 88 ± 0.53 in the calculation above).

What is the difference and meaning of that? In the latter, how would I call the value of 0.122 ( I guess that is Margin of Error)

Comment: The distinction depends on what thing you're computing an interval for. Division by $\sqrt{n}$ arises when you're taking some kind of average of $n$ things.

Comment: @Glen_b That is what I do not get - even the first calculation (without dividing by sqrt of n) is done from a sample (72 printers). Below in the comments I stated the other example: 140 children had a mean urinary lead concentration of 2.18 µmol24hr, with standard deviation 0.87. The points that include 95% of the observations are 2.18 ± (1.96 × 0.87), giving a range of 0.48 to 3.89. //// This is also a sample of n things, but they do nto divide by sqrt of 2.

Comment: Again, it's important to distinguish what quantity your interval is an interval for. An interval for containing *observations* (rather than the population mean, say) is not even a confidence interval.

Comment: @Glen_b I wish I could understand this. Let say I measure the height of 100 men, and find a mean of 177 cm and an SD of 15 cm.  This is just how the data is spread. So 68% of men are expected to have a height between 177 + - 15 cm, right? But when I talk about the mean of that specific sample, I construct the CI and divide the SD by the sqrt of the number of samples, and I will get something like  177 +- 2.94 cm. Is that correct? In addition - is the standard error for the sample virtually its standard deviation? From the normal distribution perspective.

Comment: The term *standard error* just means the standard deviation of the sampling distribution (of whatever statistic you're computing the standard error of).

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you - that is what I did not know, and was not clearly described anywhere!! Now I believe I got it!

Comment: Wikipedia has its flaws but it often has a decent opening paragraph. See the first sentence here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error

Answer (score 1):

You're mixed up about standard deviation and standard error. Consider learning the difference to be a rite of passage, as I think every statistician is confused about this early in their training.

When you see the standard error stated as $0.53$, that has already divided by $\sqrt{n}$. Standard error is the standard deviation divided by $\sqrt{n}$ (though more advanced statistics will expand on this). This means that the standard deviation is $0.53\sqrt{72} \approx 4.5$.

Then when you go to calculate the standard error, you divide the standard deviation by $\sqrt{n}$, resulting in the expected $4.5/\sqrt{72} \approx 0.53$.

The value of $0.122$ comes from mistakenly dividing the standard error, rather than the standard deviation, by $\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Very nice answer by Dave. Just one other thing. The definition of the CI at the end of the OP's statement is somewhat misleading. I would think of the CI as the following. Suppose you wrote the constructed interval on the blackboard So [lower,upper]. Next, suppose that you began drawing new observations from the population. Then, you would expect 95 percent of these new observations to fall in the bracketed interval.

Comment: @mlofton That sounds wrong. The confidence interval gets narrower and narrower as the sample size increases, while the population density stays the same. Did you mean some other kind of interval than a confidence interval?

Comment: @Dave Thanks for the answer, and you are right - in this example I overlooked it reads "error". Howerer, the question still stands, please see the following (from a book): that 140 children had a mean urinary lead concentration of 2.18 µmol24hr, with standard deviation 0.87. The points that include 95% of the observations are 2.18 ± (1.96 × 0.87), giving a range of 0.48 to 3.89. Why the range in this case is simply multiplying the SD, without taking the number of samples into consideration?

Comment: the standard deviation refers to the standard deviation of an single observation, whilst the standard error is the standard deviation of the sample mean.  you are more confident about the sample mean than a single observation and "that's why" you divide by sqrt(number of observations)

Comment: @seanv507 Well, if there is a single observation with 140 samples (the example above in the comments), why they do not divide by sqrt(140)?

Comment: That's what I just tried to explain.  If you ask for the potential variation in a single person, then its obviously more variable than the variation in the mean of say 140 samples, and so you divide the variation in a single person by the sqrt of the number used to calculate the sample mean.  imagine going around and collecting 1 million samples of the mean of 140 children and calculating the standard deviation of the means across your 1 million samples

Comment: @seanv507 But that is the thing - in this example with 140 children, they did not divide the SD by 140, they define the reference range by 1.96*SD (so -+ 2 SDs).  Why? And in the case of calculating the CI by dividing by the sqrt of the number, does the original SD still apply? Because then I will have a number +- margin of error, of which I can be 95% sure (so its like 2 SDs).

Comment: The points that include 95% of the observations are 2.18 ± (1.96 × 0.87),
The points that include 95% of the *means of 140 children* are   2.18 ± (1.96 × 0.87/sqrt(140)). They are different questions.

Comment: @seanv507 I know what you’re saying, but I’m not sure this will be clear to a beginner without some pictures and additional explanation. Perhaps you could post an answer.

Comment: I might be getting it, please correct me if I am wrong at some point: so I measure 140 samples, and get a mean and an SD. In general, I can say that wen assessing a single sample (Person), their value should fall within 2 SDs (that is the medical reference range). However, when I am talking about that population, and their actual mean, I divide te SD by its size (sqrt), which will be more precise. The only thing I am not sure of - the resultant CI with ist margin of error, can it be plotted against the original SD? Could I say that the results in the CI are within 2 SDs? I guess I cannot

Comment: Hi Dave: I could be wrong. Maybe the last line should read, "Next, suppose that you began drawing samples of $n$ observations from the population and calculating the sample mean and did this over and over again".  Then, you would expect 95 percent of these sample means to fall in the original bracketed interval. I think that's better. Let me know if you agree or if you want to stay your own definition, I'm all ears. Thanks.

Comment: @mlofton I still think that is incorrect but for a different reason. The confidence interval procedure (not any particular confidence interval) is supposed to capture the true (unknown and unknowable) parameter some amount, say $95\%$, of the time. When I simulate what you describe, I get my $95\%$ confidence interval containing about $88\%$ of the new sample means. JBStatistics did a video about this that's on YouTube that gave a number like $88\%$, though I cannot access YouTube right now to link it.

Comment: Hi Dave: Ok. Thanks for interesting explanation and simulation results. I forget where I got that definition but if someone can give the correct definition, it's appreciated. What about this one as another attempt at correction: If I performed the same CI procedure over and over and over and kept writing the resulting CI intervals on the board, then 95 percent of those intervals would contain the true mean $\mu$. I think that might be correct but I haven't simulated to check it.

Comment: That’s the correct definition of a confidence interval. @mlofton

Comment: @Dave if I may, could you look at my comment above? I still struggle a bit to see the difference: when doing the initial observation, I already do that with a sample (140 kids), but do not divide by the square root of 140...so how this does not contain the mean of the samples?